# Checking the object for null value

Tags: java

I have an object `S`, which contains the method called `getstaus()`. Now the value
of the status coming from the backend could be `null` also, so I am checking
through the following way:

```
if (S.getStatus().equals(null)) 
{}
```

Please let me know it is the correct approach or not or is there any other better approach than this.

Comment: @Lutz Horn Please _do not_ edit posts to change the coding style to your personal preference. Your edit should never have been approved.

Comment: @Lundin OK. Although I didn't approve it myself :)

Comment: @JoachimSauer ok ..removed comment but I think I can't undo my vote for close.

Answer (score 11):

Your code will throw a `NullPointerException` if `getStatus()` returns `null`, because you're trying to call a method on a reference that is `null`. Remember:  `equals()` is a method just like any other, so it requires a non-null reference.

You need to use this:

```
if (s.getStatus() == null) {
  // oh no! the status is null!
}
```

Comment: +1 for the "oh no!" comment.

Answer (score 1):

try checking like this

```
if(S.getStatus() == null){
 //You will stop here by exception
}
```